# App engine Instances placement

Tags: google-app-engine

Whenever we provision an app in app engine flexible, where does google place these instances?
In the documentation it only mentions that google manages these instances, but there is no mention of placement of these servers and how they are connected to a GCP project?

Answer (score 1):

Google does not publicly share where this instances are placed due to privacy and security reasons. The instances are managed by Google, they are very well protected. The whole point of App Engine is having your instances managed by Google so you don't have to do it yourself, how they do it should not be a concern. If you are looking to manage your own instances, take a look at [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute).

Comment: What is the point of mentioning a vpc and subnet for app engine flexible deployment?

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine is serverless, which means that's the idea, you don't have to care about servers.

> there is no mention of placement of these servers and how they are
> connected to a GCP project?

On Google Cloud, every resource is tied to a GCP project. If you access Cloud Console, you only can see it's resources after selecting a project.